# Why is sculpting not smoothing?

Tags: sculpting

For some reason, in Blender I cannot smooth part of my mesh in Sculpt Mode-[image]

I tried to smooth it by pressing Shift and smoothing, and tried smoothing it with the Smooth option in sculpting. But nothing seems to work... does anyone know how to help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to retopologize your mesh in Blender, that is the only option, the smooth brush is unable to deal with this.

These artifacts are caused by triangle fans, usually left from dynamic topology, and are impossible to smooth perfectly, because the smooth brush in Blender is not actually a smooth brush but averaging brush. If you can import this into Zbrush, there you will be able to comfortably smooth this without retopology with the [alternative smoothing mode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZ2WDozbMYI), but not in Blender.

For retopology you can use the *Remesh modifier* on a copy mesh, that you *Shrinkwrap* to the original, subdivide evenly, smooth and you continue sculpting.

Comment: Is there anyway of smoothing it without adding 2 modifiers?

Comment: @BlenderWonder You apply those modifiers, it doesn't take that long. Sadly no, there is no tool to smooth this in Blender if the topology is not nice.

Comment: I used those modifiers but it just deletes the mesh completely...

Comment: @BlenderWonder Make a duplicate of the original mesh (ctrl-d), that way the remesh modifier will change the duplicate, but you will keep the original. Then shrinkwrap the subdivided duplicate onto the original, so it is the exact shape. If the mesh dissapears anytime in the proces, that should not happen and its probably another problem to be solved.